# Classic ASP avoiding deadlock when debugging

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We have a classic ASP page that makes a request to another page on the same site to get data.

When debugging is turned on we get deadlock because the web server will only respond to one request at a time.

What is the best way to get around this limitation while still allowing us to debug it while developing?

Less than ideal options:

- Move the page to another site.
- Allow iis to use multiple processes.

Any other options?

Comment: Old school debugging parameters embedded into code.  Turn debugging on via ASP code and a variable than can be modified and write statements out to the browser.  Seems strange but that was one way that we used in the past.  Other option would be to stop using a 15+ year old technology

Comment: What version of IIS? What are you using as a debugger?

Comment: @JohnHartsock "Other option would be to stop using a 15+ year old technology" - if only life were so easy.

Comment: @Kev IIS 8.5, Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the joys of Stackoverflow, where instead of getting answers you're criticized for using Classic ASP, which is a currently supported tool even though it's been around for 100 years. :-)

I ran into a similar problem a while back while trying to create a simple script that would mimic the behavior of a script located on another server. I wanted to do some debugging without invoking the real script, so I thought I'd make a brain-dead replacement for it on my own server and invoke it the same way.

I ended up giving up and using the real script for my debugging. But today I found this KB article for you that might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316451. I'm not sure but I think that's the solution. Or something like it.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal but your always going to get haters who are going to hate. Personally I still use Classic ASP regardless of how old it is it does something's well and depending on how you use it can hold it's own against newer tech.